# Оптимальное использование статических полей при проектировании классов

Tags: c#, классы

Есть базовый абстрактный класс и 3 других класса, которые последовательно наследуют реализацию предыдущего (BaseAbstract->A->B->C). При создании нового экземпляра одного из этих трех классов, задействуется статическое поле (счетчик) в соответствующем классе для подсчета суммарного количества экземпляров конкретного класса, вывод которого осуществляется через статический метод.

```
abstract class BaseAbstract
{
    public BaseAbstract()
    {
        //инициализация полей абстрактного класса

        IncStaticField();   //вызов абстрактного метода в конструкторе абстрактного класса
    }
    protected abstract void IncStaticField();
}

class A : BaseAbstract 
{
    private static int instNo = 0;  //стат. поле

    protected override void IncStaticField()
    {
        A.instNo = A.instNo + 1;   //тип указываю здесь лишь для "пояснения" собственных намерений
    }

    public static string Info()     //вывод кол-ва созданных экземпляров конкретного класса
    {
        return "Общее количество созданных экземпляров класса A: " + instNo;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    private static int instNo = 0;

    protected override void IncStaticField()
    {
        B.instNo = B.instNo + 1;
    }

    public static new string Info()     // замещение
    {
        return "Общее количество созданных экземпляров класса B: " + instNo;
    }
}

class C : B
{
    //аналогичная реализация, как в классе B
}
```

Данная реализация успешно подсчитывает кол-во созданных экземпляров для каждого класса и выводит их значения через вызов метода Info() конкретного класса.

1) Насколько безопасным является вызов абстрактного (виртуального) метода в конструкторе, благодаря которому и происходит увеличение статического поля конкретного класса?

2) Можно ли упростить реализацию метода IncStaticField(), дабы не приходилось объявлять его в каждом классе лишь для указания класса статического поля которое следует увеличить?

Answer (score 3):

Для начала пару слов про ваш код:

> public static new string Info()     // замещение

`new` в данном случае не требуется, т.к. CLR, вообще, и C#, в частности, не поддерживают наследование статических членов, соответственно никакой проблемы с одноименными статическими методами в классах наследниках не возникнет.

> 1) Насколько безопасным является вызов абстрактного (виртуального)
>   метода в конструкторе, благодаря которому и происходит увеличение
>   статического поля конкретного класса?

Если абстрактный/виртуальный метод корректно реализован/переопределен с использованием `override`, то все будет нормально. Но проблема с вероятностью возникнет, если виртуальный метод не переопределен в классе и вызывает метод базового класса, который еще не был инстанцирован. Поэтому в целом такой подход не желателен, т.к. мы не можем заставить производный класс принудительно переопределить виртуальный метод.

> 2) Можно ли упростить реализацию метода IncStaticField(), дабы не
>   приходилось объявлять его в каждом классе лишь для указания класса
>   статического поля которое следует увеличить?

Если метод используется исключительно для увеличения счетчика объектов, то почему бы не заменить его на обычный `instNo++` в конструкторе? Таким образом определять метод в каждом классе не нужно. А вот более сложную логику, если она есть/нужна, уже можно выпилить в отдельный метод, и переопределять его по мере необходимости.

Ну и напоследок полезная статья про статические члены классов и классы:
[Эрик Браун **Семь советов по применению статических полей, методов и классов**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335949.aspx)

Comment: Указывая new в объявлении метода, я попросту избавляюсь от очередного предупреждения (отключать их не намерен).

Comment: @S.Butaev так `new` у `static` метода не избавляет от предупреждения, а вызывает ошибку

Comment: Ну в чистом C# у меня ошибки не возникает (компилируется успешно ведь)

Comment: Насчет вызова виртуального метода в конструкторе:
При использовании виртуальных методов в конструкторах, может возникнуть ситуация когда производный класс будет исполнять код метода, взаимодействующий с полями, до их непосредственной инициализации. Это вопрос скорее из разряда "Следует ли мне делать экземпляры структурного типа неизменяемыми?", так как в моей конкретной ситуации я четко осознаю какой конструктор когда будет вызываться.

Comment: @S.Butaev .NET 4.5 и VS 2013 кидает ошибку еще до компиляции, хотя может у меня в студии более высокие требования выставлены к коду, не проверял. А если не секрет, как вы собираетесь структуру сделать неизменяемой если она value-type и все поля по определению public? класс можно и нужно, по возможности, сделать неизменяемым, а структуру не получится.

Comment: Я просто достаточно часто слышу (и вычитываю у того же Рихтера) о нежелательности подобной реализации, нашел кстати подобный вопрос на англоязычном SO:
[Virtual member call in a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor)

Comment: ну для immutable-ных структур можно сделать их поля readonly  (структуры к моему вопросу не имеют отношения, правда), не очень понимаю что вы имеете ввиду "по определению public" (у меня по умолчанию поля идут как закрытые).
ReadOnly полностью неизменяемым структуру сделать не сможет:
http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/07/01/when-is-a-readonly-field-not-readonly/

Comment: @S.Butaev struct в C# это в некотором смысле "недокласс", они не поддерживают наследование, вертикальный полиморфизм и ограниченно поддерживают инкапсуляцию, отдельные методы могут private. Поля в любом случае будут public, это ограничение типов на базе struct. Типы на базе class, поддерживают все ООП фичи C#

Comment: про "недоклассность" структур я знаком, (хотя все они неявно наследуются от System.ValueType который, в свою очередь наследуется от System.Object, да и интерфейсы для них никто не отменял, хотя интерфейсы не наследуют, а реализуют). Это все офф-топик, если честно.
Если же  у вас есть идея как можно при помощи структур решить текущую проблему, я с радостью готов это прочитать.

Comment: @S.Butaev так про текущую проблему я написал, делайте инкремент прямо в конструкторе, без метода. Ради одного инкремента делать отдельный метод не вижу глубокого смысла. тем более что он у вас не публичный.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, могу предложить завести в самом базовом классе одно статическое поле -- словарь (Dictionary) с ключом -- тип класса либо название типа класса, и значением int. И один метод (невиртуальный), который и будет всё делать. В метод передаём Type. Принцип работы метода такой: увеличить счётчик в словаре для переданного типа, затем по reflection взять для этого типа тип-родитель, увеличить счётчик в словаре для него итд. Ну и обеспечить вызов этого метода-счётчика из конструктора каждого порождённого класса.
Плюсы -- никаких виртуальных вызовов в конструкторе.
Минусы -- использование рефлексии, снижающее производительность.